# How do I make sure an OptionButton.Value has been chosen

Tags: excel, vba, vb6, if-statement

I currently making an Excel VB application. However, I am stuck at the moment. I am trying to make the choice between two OptionButtons compulsory.

I tried the code

```
If Me.PWebOption.Value = False & Me.BWebOption = False Then
        MsgBox "Please choose a type of website"
        Exit Sub
End If
```

But this is not giving me the required results. I tried putting them in brackets and everything but still stuck. I'm sure this is a trivial answer but I am just getting to grips with VB so please forgive me.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your code and it works if you **change & to And**. I created 2 OptionButtons, named them and ran the code with "And" without problems.

If it still doesn't work then my guess is that:

- one or both of your OptionButtons is not false

or:

- you are accessing the wrong OptionButtons.

Try

```
Debug.Print Me.PWebOption.Value
Debug.Print Me.BWebOption.Value
Debug.Print Me.PWebOption 'just for fun'
Debug.Print Me.BWebOption
```

It should all return false. Also try putting `Option Explicit` at the head of your Code to ensure you are only accessing objects that actually exist.

**Note:** In VBA & is only used for concatenation and: And, Or and Not are the logical operators.

Comment: Cheers marg. That was just what I needed to do.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it's a copy/paste error or not, but in the first part you're calling `.Value` and in the second part you're just using the option itself. Should your code be this instead:

```
If Me.PWebOption.Value = False & Me.BWebOption.Value = False Then 
        MsgBox "Please choose a type of website" 
        Exit Sub 
End If
```

(Note that it's using `.Value` on both options.)